# How to get scroll position after stop scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var scrollVal;
  $(".book-body").scroll(function(){
  scrollVal = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(scrollVal);
});
```

Above is my code and this will console.log the scroll position when scroll.
However, the number keeps showing on console.

What can I do to make it only show one position data after I stop scroll?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, Since you have written `console.log()` within the scroll function, it will obviously show the numbers when scrolling. If you need to get the scroll position when you stop scrolling, you could use `scrollstop()` for that. Try something like this:

```
$(".book-body").on("scrollstop",function(){
    console.log($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

Not sure if this will answer you question, but maybe this comes close.

Answer (score 0):

I have been using that in one of my project

```
$(".book-body").scroll(function() {
  clearTimeout($.data(this, 'scrollTimer'));
  $.data(this, 'scrollTimer', setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("Haven't scrolled in 1000ms!");
  }, 1000));
});
```

it will trigger a function 1s after scroll stop, but you can customize that.